# is it best practice to define wrapper outside of test/it in jest?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Which is best practice and why? -

This one i define the wrapper inside each of the tests

```js
it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App.WrappedComponent />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('tests something else', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App.WrappedComponent />);
    const title = wrapper.find('AppTitle');
    expect(title.childAt(2).text()).toBe('React App!');
});
```

or

This one i define the wrapper outside each of the tests

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<App.WrappedComponent />);
it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('tests something else', () => {
    const title = wrapper.find('AppTitle');
    expect(title.childAt(2).text()).toBe('React App!');
});
```

Just wondering there is any memory issues or etc. by defining it outside the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test code follows the same principles as other code.
In particular you shouldn't repeat yourself without necessity.

You may use `beforeEach` to re-create the objects which each test need.
Now let's get to some of the pros and cons for the alternative you have showed us:

Pros:

- Easy to read, just one central definition (applies to `beforeEach` and `beforeAll` as well)
- If your wrapper creation is computationally expensive it may be faster (that should be tested)

Cons:

- If your wrapper has some state, one test may change it and leak that to other tests, this is probably not you want in your test suite
- If the wrapper is not used in all tests you are holding it in memory longer than necessary (the garbage collector might not be able to collect it) which in fact increases memory usage. If you run only a few fast tests this might not be negligible.

My personal recommendation for common unit test scenarios with as few assumptions as possible is: re-create your SUTs (subjects under test) for each test in a `beforeEach` method.

This will minimize state-cross-talking between tests and your are only defining it in one place.

Comment: Each test should be specific and useful. If DRY introduces complexity and logic in tests then it should be avoided.